# How to sum arrays vertically in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to sum arrays, vertically, using just a single formula. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
5,3,1
-----
4,5,6
-----
2,9,3
-----

--> 11,17,10
```

Another example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kbJ.png]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A3, ","))), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1:A3, ",")), 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

[image]